# Redis match with single quotes

Tags: redis

Hi I have redis sets with members

```
"{id:3,url:'Twitter.com'}"
"{id:1,url:'Facebook.com'}"
"{id:2,url:'Google.com'}"
```

How can I use scan command to search member that url starts with F

I've tried `SSCAN xurl 0 MATCH *url:'F?'*` but it said invalid argument(s)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

`invalid argument(s)` returned since the closed quotes in your input followed by non space characters (`*`). That's not allowed.

if the input string contains single quotes, you can put them into double quotes like this:

```
SSCAN xurl 0 MATCH "*url:'F*'*"
```

Or:

```
SSCAN xurl 0 MATCH '*url:\'F*\'*'
```

BTW: the character `?` in match option means there's a single character at that place. Replace it with `*` will be fine. [Redis match patterns](https://redis.io/commands/keys)